# jqtouch b4 issue with compiling scss

Tags: sass, jqtouch, compass-sass

I downloaded the latest version of jqtouch and nicely enough it has scss theming now. All fine and dandy except im either doing something very wrong or ...

Issue is as follows. I extract the archive contents then go to themes\scss and run a compass watch

here's what comes out

```
>>> Change detected at 05:47:54 to: apple.scss
error apple.scss (Line 39 of _gradients.scss: Invalid null operation: ""glossy" neq null".)
```

create ../css/apple.css
    error jqtouch.scss (Line 39 of _gradients.scss: Invalid null operation: ""glossy" neq null".)
   create ../css/jqtouch.css
    error vanilla.scss (Line 39 of _gradients.scss: Invalid null operation: ""flat" neq null".)
   create ../css/vanilla.css

Have absolutelly no idea how to fix it. Any clues would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had this same problem when using compass with sencha touch scss. If you might run into this please consider uninstalling ruby and everything pertaining to it and reinstalling from scratch (ruby,compass etc)